# Why is PhpStorm indexing outside my project folder?

Tags: phpstorm

I have two separate Drupal 8 sites that I am working on locally; each has a separate project in PhpStorm. There is nothing shared between projects.

When I'm working on "Project A" I am getting "Multiple definition exists for class..." messages all over the place. Strangely, when I command click on an instance of one of these classes I am presented a choice of which definition I want to open: the one from "Project A" (`.../path/to/class`) or the same class from "Project B" (`/absolute/path/to/projectb/path/to/class`).

How can I get PhpStorm to stop looking in "Project B" for class definitions?

**version info:**

- PhpStorm 2017.3.6
- Build #PS-173.4674.46, built on March 15, 2018 ...

Comment: Looks like you have those projects attached. Try opening View > Tools windows > Project. Switch to "Project" scope and make sure there's only 1 project listed.

Comment: Turned out I had some include paths under preferences->langs&Frameworks->PHP that were the culprits.